# Program compiles and executes without header files turbo c++

Tags: c, turbo-c++

I'm a noob in programming. 
My teacher compiled a program without any pre-processor directive at all and it executed and displayed output.
It was just a hello world program. 
I'm confused that without the directives how it was able to carry out the "printf" function.

Comment: Why not? What you need preprocessor for? The actual compilation phase compiles the file without any preprocessor stuff

Comment: `printf`? So the teacher actually used `printf`.

Answer (score 3):

In "classic" ANSI C (C89/90) you can call non-variadic functions without pre-declaring them, as long as you are careful about supplying arguments of proper type. So, if one does everything properly, one can write a formally valid C89/90 program that does not include any standard headers. E.g.

```
int main()
{
  puts("Hello World");
  return 0;
}
```

In modern C that would not be possible, since starting from C99 all functions have to be declared before being called.

Now, calling `printf` without pre-declaring it (with prototype) caused undefined behavior even in C89/90, since `printf` is a variadic function. So, if your teacher did something like that

```
int main()
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

then he/she still has a lot to learn about C. This C89/90 program is not valid, even if it compiled, executed and displayed output that "looked fine" to you.

However, you can still pre-declare the function manually

```
​int printf(const char *format, ...);​

int main()
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

and end up with a valid C89/90 program that does not use any preprocessing directives. Doing it that way is not a good programming practice though.

Comment: I tried out your "puts" code on TurboC++, but it shows an error saying that puts must have a prototype.

Comment: @AlphaMineron Firstly, you have to make sure you are compiling your code as C, not as C++. Secondly, it has to be the "old" C - C89/90.